# Unable to install NVidia Driver 352

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, gpu

I have a **HP Envy 15-ae009tx** laptop.

- Ubuntu 14.04 OS
- i7-5500U processor
- NVidia GeForce GTX 950M

I tried using `sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 352-updates`.

On reboot, the screen shows dots in the purple screen and runs into a login loop. I keep uninstalling it by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*`.

Can someone tell me how to correctly install the graphics driver?

Comment: Open software and updates -> additional driver  -> select your driver then apply change

Comment: I tried that also. Same result. Ubuntu gets stuck on a login loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First uninstall all already installed NVIDIA drivers software ... boot the PC.
Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password - execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now reinstall the drivers 352.63 supporting NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 950M.
Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password - execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Note :
In case `nouveau.modeset=0` doesn't work, set the parameter `nomodeset` instead.

**Update addressing your response that the drivers installation failed :**

Check whether there is a switch in BIOS to activate the NVIDIA adapter.
If this is the case - change the settings to use the NVIDIA graphics card.

Uninstall all NVIDIA related software ...
Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password - execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Install the latest official NVIDIA drivers ...
Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password - execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Note :

Generally you should use the drivers from the official Ubuntu repositories. But when you have problems with these drivers, you can install the more current drivers from the GPU Drivers PPA. This often leads to properly working graphics, especially on very new NVIDIA GEFORCE adapters.

Comment: Nope. I end up with the same problem even after following this. What to do?

Comment: Where do you learn all this?

Comment: Does the device driver and device controller have any link as such? As the problem arose on both occasions(yeah i reset my pc the first time around) after i installed the nvidia game ready driver v358 on my windows... @cl-netbox

Comment: @KailashKarthik : These graphics adapter things are not trivial - everything depends on the collaboration between the drivers, the kernels and the hardware. On nearly every machine there are some differences - so unfortunately there is no general way to learn how to achieve a working solution. The only way to gain knowledge is to test everything on as many machines as possible ... and this is what I have done for some long period of time. :)

Comment: can u help me with this http://askubuntu.com/q/809734/483463 @cl-netbox